# Userform initialize without rewriting data in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been wondering about this one for a while now.

Let's say I have a formula in A1, Worksheet("Main")

```
=IF(B2="English";"Good morning";"Guten Morgan")
```

Then I have userform with code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A1").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.TextBox1.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

How can I make it work so, that if I don't input anything into textbox, it will keep displaying functions result. If I will start to type text into textbox it will input my typed text to A1. Now if I open the userform it will overwrite A1 with the text in textbox and there will be no formula anymore. So if I change language in B2 result will no longer be interfaced into textbox.

Can be also some other approach with VBA. Everything is acceptable as long as logic will work.

I have tried to use textbox properly, something like linkedsource or similar, but it is crashing excel workbook sometimes. That's why I am trying to avoid it.

---

**EDIT:**

Thank you for suggestions! I have tried to implement this somehow but still don't get it. I am creating variable where I want to store result from `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("L49").Value` then I would like to use it in `Userform Me.TextBox14.Text` to be displayed. Then once it is changed in Me.TextBox14.Text and Enter button has been pressed it should change also in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("L49").Value`.

Here is my current code I am trying to play with:

```
Private ProjectClass As String

Private Sub TextBox14_Enter()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("L49").Value = ProjectClass
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.TextBox14.Text = ProjectClass
End Sub
```

Comment: Its because you have linked the spreadsheet cells directly to the Textbox.  What you should do instead is to have a set of local variables which are used to capture info from the spreadsheet and display it in the text box but which are not written back to the spreadsheet until you click OK or not written back to the spreadsheet if you click cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBox.Enter` event isn't fired when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but when *the control* is entered - that is, when it gets the focus and a caret/cursor starts blinking inside it. You'll want to update the backing variable when the value is *modified*:

```
Private Sub TextBox14_Enter()
    'runs when the control gets focus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox14_Exit()
    'runs when the control loses focus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox14_Change()
    'runs whenever the value changes (real-time)
End Sub
```

So in this case I'd go with the `TextBox.Change` event handler, and make it update the variable (not the worksheet):

```
Private ProjectClass As String

Private Sub TextBox14_Change()
    ProjectClass = TextBox14.Text
End Sub
```

Now the problem is that the `ProjectClass` value needs to be accessible from outside the form, so that the caller can set an initial value. One way to do this could be to expose it as a property - one property (get+let) for each field you want to seed a value for:

```
Public Property Get ProjClass() As String
    ProjClass = ProjectClass
End Property

Public Property Let ProjClass(ByVal value As String)
    ProjectClass = value
    ApplyModelProperties
End Property

Private Sub ApplyModelProperties()
    TextBox14.Text = ProjectClass
    '...
End Sub
```

Now from outside the form, at the call site (the code that's showing this dialog), you can seed the value from the worksheet, and the form never needs to know or care that a worksheet was involved:

```
With New UserForm1
    .ProjClass = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("L49").Value
    .Show
    MsgBox .ProjClass
End With
```

Note that because the value is exposed as a property, the calling code doesn't need to know about `TextBox14` anymore.